# Add policy to the auto created IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have cdk script which makes one `S3 bucket` and `lambda` then add s3 trigger to lambda

```
const up_bk = new s3.Bucket(this, 'cdk-st-in-bk', { // image-resize用のbucket
  bucketName: `cdk-st-${targetEnv}-resource-in-bk`,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  cors: [{
      allowedMethods: [
        s3.HttpMethods.GET,
        s3.HttpMethods.POST,
        s3.HttpMethods.PUT,
        s3.HttpMethods.DELETE,
        s3.HttpMethods.HEAD,
      ],
      allowedHeaders: ["*"],
      allowedOrigins: ["*"],
      exposedHeaders: ["ETag"],
      maxAge: 3000
    }]
});

const resizerLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "ResizerLambda", {
  code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("resizer-sam/resizer"),
});

resizerLambda.addEventSource(new S3EventSource(up_bk, { 
  events: [ s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED ],
}));
```

Now,It makes role automatically `st-dev-base-stack-ResizerLambdaServiceRoleAE27CE82-1LWJL0D35A0GW`

But it has only `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`

So,when I try to access S3 from bucket there comes error like `

For example,

```
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj_key)

"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied"
```

I guess I should add the `AmazonS3FullAccess` to this role.

However how can I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the Lambda function permission to read from the bucket:

```
up_bk.grantRead(resizerLambda);
```

If you also need it to write to the bucket, do:

```
up_bk.grantReadWrite(resizerLambda);
```

Comment: Thank you it is very simple example for the way of making permission. I understood